# PHP routine sending APNS push notifications via AWS causes 500 internal server error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have PHP sitting on a GoDaddy server that sends push notification requests to the Apple Push Notification Service via Amazon's push notification service.

Intermittently when sending push notifications to 20+ users the user initiating sending the notifications gets a GoDaddy Internal Server 500 error.

I've traced specific DeviceTokens that caused the failure and used the same routine to send notifications to these specific DeviceTokens and they work - so I assume the issue is intermittent and unrelated to any particular DeviceToken.

I'm suspicious of:
(1) the exception handler which I've updated to catch AWSExceptions
(2) the issue occurs when sending to 20+ devices, so perhaps it's a timeout issue (I do have set timeout=0 on the PHP page)

Here is the code - truly hoping someone can help:

```
static public function send_push_notification($message, $token, $badge = 1)
    {               
        $sns = SnsClient::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key' => '<redacted>',
                'secret' => '<redacted>'
            ),
            'region' => 'us-west-1',
            'version' => '2010-03-31'
        ));
        $ios_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:<redacted>";
        $ios_endpoints = $sns->listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(array(
            'PlatformApplicationArn' => $ios_arn
        ));
        $arn = "";
        foreach ($ios_endpoints['Endpoints'] as $endpoint) {
            if ($token == $endpoint['Attributes']['Token']) {
                $arn = $endpoint['EndpointArn'];
            }
        }
        if ($arn == "") {       
            $arn = SNSPushNotifications::register_device($token);
        }       
        try {
            $contents          = array();
            $contents['badge'] = $badge;
            $contents['alert'] = addslashes($message);
            $contents['sound'] = "default";
            $push              = array(
                "aps" => $contents
            );
            $push_json         = json_encode($push);
            $json              = json_encode(array(
                'APNS' => $push_json
            ));

            $sns->publish(array(
                'MessageStructure' => 'json',
                'Message' => $json,
                'TargetArn' => $arn
            ));
        }       
        catch (AWSException $e) {   
         $mess=$e->getAwsRequestId() . "\n";
         $mess.=$e->getAwsErrorType() . "\n";
         $mess.=$e->getAwsErrorCode() . "\n";

         $m="Push notification sent to ".get_token_user($token)."($token) failed: " . $endpointArn . "<br/><strong>Error:</strong> " . $mess . "<br/>";

           $headers = "From: <redacted>\r\n"; 
           $headers .= "Reply-To: <redacted>\r\n";
           $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            mail("<redacted>","Push Notification Failure",$m, $headers);                  
         if ($mess=="Endpoint is disabled") delete_token($token);    
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 500 you are getting is not from the function above (static keyword goes after `public`).

From the Apple Developer documentation: "It can take a while for the dropped connection to make its way from APNs back to your server just because of normal latency. It's possible to send over 500 notifications before a write fails because of the connection being dropped..." Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

It would be helpfull if you can pull out the backtrace error log from Goddady.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the static to the right position.

I'm using GoDaddy Linux shared hosting, any idea where or how I can access the backtrace error log?

Comment: What message you get in the AWSException?